# How to increase database performance if there is 0.1M traffic

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I am developing a site and I'm concerned about the performance.

In the current system there are transactions like adding 10,000 rows to a single table. It doesn't matter it took around 0.6 seconds to insert.

But I am worrying about what happens if there are 100,000 concurrent users and 1000 of the users want to add 10,000 rows to a single table at once.

How could this impact the performance compared to a single user? How can I improve these transactions if there is a large amount of traffic like in this situation?

Comment: You get faster hard drives, ones which are able to squeeze so much info through the controller to the permanent storage. This includes SSDs and various RAID levels. You're basically looking for a high IOPS solid state disk. There is only so much you can achieve by software tweaks, when the software hits the limit of the hardware - it's time for better hardware and distribution strategies. Also, before NoSQL fans jump in - NoSQLs suffer from the same problem.

Comment: What do you use storage engine? **InnoDB**? when your table has alot of rows, **MyISAM** is more better storage engine option.

Comment: @Fatemeh That fully depends on the setup and the transactions issued and can not be given as a general recommendation! If you have parallel insersts and reads for instance, MyISAM is blocking the entire table during insert and slowing down all selects, in this case InnoDB is much better.

Comment: @AxelAmthor who said MyISAM is blocking the entire table during insert ?

Comment: @Fatemeh - your "opinion" here is from 2006. MyISAM is never a better storage choice than InnoDB is. Quite literally - **never**.

Comment: @N.B. I have 5 dictionary table that has +200,000 rows each of them, when i search into them: MyISAM (take 0,4 sec), InnoDB (take 0,9 sec)

Comment: @Fatemeh - that means nothing to me. You obviously don't know about configuring MySQL and what the two engines really do. Also, I have a few 10-terabyte MySQLs that I work with, and trust me - MyISAM doesn't cut it there.

Comment: @N.B. I don't know what should i say ...! maybe you right, I just told my experiences, anyway tnx for your attention.

Comment: @Fatemeh - InnoDB and MyISAM measure about the same with small amount of data. InnoDB has a variable called `innodb_buffer_pool_size` - increasing its value makes all searches and what not much quicker since MySQL will use RAM to cache the working data set. This is what you can't achieve with MyISAM. That part of design is what makes InnoDB super quick for selects, and it even outperforms things like Memcache when it comes to access speeds.

Comment: @N.B. all right, just tell me when using of MyISAM is the best option ?

Comment: In this day and age, probably never. Maybe on machines that are super hardware constrained and when you don't need to be sure that the data is written down. Personally, I never use it.

Comment: Hey guys!  quit with the pissing war!  Neither engine can handle 1K*10K rows being inserted as fast as the OP would like.

Answer (score 3):

When **write** speed is mandatory, the way we tackle it is getting quicker hard drives.
You mentioned transactions, that means you need your data durable (D of ACID). This requirement rules out MyISAM storage engine or any type of NoSQL so I'll focus the answer towards what goes on with relational databases.

The way it works is this: you get a set number of Input Output Operations per Second or IOPS per hard drive. Hard drives also have a metric called bandwith. The metric you are interested in is **write speed**. 
Some crude calculation here would be this - Number of MB per second divided by number of IOPS = how much data you can squeeze per IOPS.

For mechanical drives, this magic IOPS number is anywhere between 150 and 300 - quite low. Given their bandwith of about 100 MB/sec, you get a real small number of writes and bandwith per write. This is where Solid State Drives kick in - their IOPS number starts at about 5 000 (some even go to 80 000) which is awesome for databases.

Connecting these drives in RAID gives you a super quick storage solution. If you are able to squeeze 10 000 inserts into one transaction, the disk will try to squeeze all 10k inserts through 1 IOPS.

Another strategy is partitioning your table and having multiple drives where MySQL stores the data.

This is as far as you can go with a single MySQL installation. There are strategies for distributing data to multiple MySQL nodes etc. but I assume that's out of scope of your question.

TL;DR: you need quicker disks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to scale for inserting millions of rows per second, you have bigger problems.  That could add up to trillions of rows per month.  That's hundreds of terabytes before the end of the month.  Do you have a big enough disk farm for that?  Can you afford enough SSDs for that.

Another thing.  With a trillion rows, it is quite challenging to have any indexes other than a simple auto_increment.  Without any indexes, how do you plan on accessing the data?  A table scan of a trillion rows will take day(s).

Also, you said 100,000 users; you implied that they are connected simultaneously?  That, too, is a challenge.

What are the users doing to generate 10K rows all at once?  What about the network bandwidth?

Etc. Etc.

If you really have a task like this, Sharding is probably the only solution.  And that is *in addition to* SSDs, RAID, IOPs, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Few stuff that you must consider both from software and hardware point.

Things must consider :

> 1. Go for SSD drive to have better IO.
> 2. Good to have 10GB of network, if you have that huge traffic.
> 3. Use mysql 5.6 or above, they made good improvement on performance over previous version.
> 4. Use bulk inserts, instead of sequential one, and even better if you can store all data in a file and use load_data_infile. This would be
>      20 times faster then regular insert.

Mysql provide multiple ways to scaleout. Its depend upon on your product requirement which way you want to go.